# Why doesn't MailAddress quote the DisplayName when there is a comma?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

We've recently migrated from .NET 2 to .NET 4 and the System.Net.Mail.MailAddress class is giving me a headache. Previously, if I had an email (joe@example.com) and a displayname (Joe Smith, CEO®) you could do:

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("joe@example.com", "Joe Smith, CEO®");
```

And you'd get a properly formatted `"Joe Smith, CEO" <joe@example.com>` when emailed. This was viewable/readable/etc. by all mailers.

With .NET 4 Outlook/Exchange are throwing a fit on how this is encoded, splitting it on the Comma: `<=?utf-8?Q?Joe@gwm.example.com>, CEO=C2=AE?= <joe@example.com>` which causes it to not be decoded properly.

[From Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> A comma is used to separate elements in a list of mail addresses. As a
>   result, a comma should not be used in unquoted display names in a
>   list.

Which is fine, but when you do:

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("joe@example.com", "\"Joe Smith, CEO®\"");
```

The quotes are stripped because;

> This method removes surrounding quotes not displayed by the
>   DisplayName property.

So how do you tell MailAddress that the comma it doesn't want *should be quoted*, without adding an extra space (such as "\u200B\"Joe...\"") that makes the address indent in the mail reader?

**UPDATE**

Microsoft's Answer (see response comments for link):

> Posted by Microsoft on 8/17/2011 -- Thank you for your
>   feedback. This is a well known issue and a patch is currently being
>   created for .NET 4.0. To obtain the patch please contact Microsoft
>   Support directly regarding **KB 2576045**.

Comment: "(No live data was harmed in asking this question)" -> Why do people not simply use the [example domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com). Every non-example address might be, become or have been a valid address. Paranoid programmers should know and respect that.

Comment: @phresnel Thanks for the link, wasn't aware of them. Updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

didn't test it but try

```
 MailAddress from = new MailAddress("joe@nospam.com", "Joe Smith\",\" CEO®");
```

EDIT - another option:

```
 MailAddress from = new MailAddress("joe@nospam.com", "Joe Smith\x2C CEO®");
```

Comment: Almost! Looks fine in outlook `Joe Smith, CEO...";` looks awkward in Gmail `Joe Smith"," CEO...`

Comment: No luck, I tried that too. Any comma, Unicode or Hex, goes through and causes problems.

Comment: file that as a bug with MS, tell your users to use "-" instead of "," in the Display name or to only care about receipients with Outlook :-)

Comment: [Bug with Microsoft filed!](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/684327/system-net-mail-mailaddress-doesnt-quote-comma-in-display-name#tabs) We'll see what happens. The work around is to do `" \"Joe Smith,...\""` or `"\"Joe Smith,...\" "` - the extra space causes the quotes to be put back in.